# Loops in R programming,

Tags: r, data-mining, dataset, data, data-cleaning

I want to update this Remaining column in this table below:
[image]

How do I do this in R programming?

I tried

**while (n.Remaining>0)**

**{ n.remaining <- n.total-n.expense}**

Desired Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in R you just need to do `10-cumsum(expense)`. This will give you the Remaining column

Answer (score 0):

More complicated than a `cumsum`, but `for` loop could look something like:

```
for (j in 3:5){
       n[j,'Remaining'] <- n[j-1,'Remaining'] - n[j,'expense']}
```

If your answer needs to be strictly positive, think about including a `while` or `if` statement.